# Выбор среды Java

Tags: java

Собираюсь учить java, какие тонкости у этого языка? И какую среду выбрать? Есть ли среда с визуальным редактором? До этого писал на c#, php, js, и немного actionscript.

Comment: > Есть ли среда с визуальным редактором

С визуальным редактором чего?

Comment: Форм, а вообще я и спросил про тонкости языка, куда ещё можно запихать визуальный редактор?

Comment: В Java нет тонкостей: там все все толсто-толсто :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду визуальный редактор Swing, то лучше всего для начала подойдет NetBeans.

Comment: Eclipse RCP / SWT

Answer (score 1):

Советую попробовать IntelliJ IDEA. На мой взгляд самая удачная среда для разработки. Есть бесплатная версия.